# Is Chapter 66 the last chapter of Rosario Vampire Season II manga?

Tags: rosario-vampire

Is chapter 66 the true ending for *Season II*? According to Akihisa Ikeda, this chapter would be the last chapter and for three months I could not find any more pages after this. However, it seems it's still "to be continued" as mentioned on the page.

[image: "The last of the three great dark lords."]

Is this the last page/chapter?

Comment: The weird part is the to be continued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is going to be an epilogue released in *Jump SQ.19*'s April 14th issue. As to whether it's a season epilogue or for the manga as a whole is unknown. If it's received well and doesn't write them into a hole as far as the story goes, then I would say a 3rd manga season would be very likely to recoup the losses from season 2 of the anime. After all the manga still did fairly well.

Comment: "The epilogue chapter will be published in Jump Square 19's 13th issue on April 19." I can confirm

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you for correcting that. I should have double checked before I posted that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is the ending of Rosario Vampire Season II. There are chapter 66.2 to 66.6 but the picture your showing is indeed the last one story wise.

The chances of more chapters to come is very unlikely aswell as stated on [Funimation](http://www.funimation.com/forum/showthread.php?497-%2aDo-NOT-Request-Rosario-Vampire-season-3-%2a)

> Rosario+Vampire season 2 bombed in Japan. Hard. It did so poorly it almost put GONZO out of business. Because of poor sales, there are no plans at this time for a third season. That's not to say it's entirely impossible, but the way things are going it is incredibly unlikely.
>   - [See more here](http://www.funimation.com/forum/showthread.php?497-%2aDo-NOT-Request-Rosario-Vampire-season-3-%2a#sthash.xeovuCwe.dpuf)

Comment: Would you mind edit the quote out, or make it consistent with what the question is asking. The quote is talking about the anime, while the question is asking about the manga.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is an additional few chapters that show him fighting Alucard. It ends at chapter 66.6 and apparently, there was an epilogue released recently .

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, this also includes the epilogue they may release more but perhaps under a different name since the Rosario was destroyed and the name *Rosario + Vampire* is no longer able to be referenced due to that simple fact, and Tsukune is a vampire now and the outer Moka is gone. Perhaps the name would be changed.

It also said that "Yoshii Kiria took over fairy tail" and then state "but let's save that story for another time". At least from what I understand of the wording, it is passable for a continuation of *Rosario + Vampire*, but would most likely no longer be called that anymore. This comes from "Dawn of the Dark" arc of the manga as Tsukune is being trained by Moka's father, Shuzen Issa in the after story.